# Angular+Web API не отправляется запрос

Tags: веб-программирование, angular, webapi

Всем привет! Проблема с отправкой POST-запроса с фронта(Angular 8) на бэк(Web API).
CORS на бэке добавил глобально, и GET-запросы проходят шикарно. А вот POST.
У меня фронт это Angular приложение на одном локальном серве, а бэк Web API на другом локальном серве.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { NgModel } from "@angular/forms";

    @Component({
      selector: "my-app",
      templateUrl: "./Views/MainPage/MainPage.html",
      styleUrls: ["./wwwroot/Styles/LoginStyles.css"]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}  
      onSignIn() {
        let login: string = "test",
          password: string = "123";
        const body = {
          sLogin: login,
          sPassword: password
        };    
        const url: string = "https://localhost:44320/api/auth/signin";   
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();    
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POsST,PUT");
        headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");  
        this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers}).subscribe(oResponse => {
          console.log(oResponse);
        });
      }
    }
```

C#

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Http.Cors;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using MillitaryBookServices.Models;

    namespace MillitaryBookServices.Controllers.Auth {
        [Route("api/auth")]
        [ApiController]
        [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        public class AuthController {
            [HttpPost]
            [Route("signin")]
            public void SignIn([FromBody] SignIn data) {   // Сюда не проваливается
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("sig")]
            public void GetSignIn(int id) {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }        
        }
    }
```

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        namespace MillitaryBookServices.Models {
            public class SignIn {
                public string Login { get; set; }
                public string Password { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если бы вы ошибку привели текстом, то кто-то мог бы попробовать вбить её в гугл и поискать что-то на этот счёт.

Comment: Вообще, похоже, на бэке CORS не совсем верно настроен. Возможно надо дополнительные заголовки приписать для некоторых браузеров. Покажите настройки бэка на этот счёт и уточните какой у вас браузер (возможно в другом будет работать)

Comment: Да, похоже что дело в бэке.. Воо ошибка текстом..

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44320/api/auth/signin' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Я настроил CORS глобально в startap.cs

Comment: Вот моя настройка на бэке
 services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", b => {
                    b.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader();
                        //.AllowCredentials();
                }
                );
            });

Comment: Я пробовал добавлять заголовки в запрос с фронта. Но ничего не изменилось. В гугле некоторые пишут, что надо наоборот удалить заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Но не понимаю каким образом.

Comment: Заголовки надо на сервере настраивать, не на фронте. Сложно гуглить решение для незнакомой технологии - добавьте в вопрос что именно у вас такое на бэке, а то мне гугл код с другими, кажется, либами выдаёт. Видел в гугле советы вместо разрешения всего сразу перечислять что нужно разрешить.

Answer (score 1):

не нужно из angular-a отправить эти header-и,

это response header-и которые отправляет бэкенд.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

```
  headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POsST,PUT");
  headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, 
  Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, 
  Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

и кажется в бэкендe нужно настроить CORS-и так, чтобы он принимал header с именем `Content-Type`

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за наводку в сторону настройки CORS на бэке. Все ответы привели меня к такому решению, которое сработало для меня.
Нужно было добавить в файле Startap.cs

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder => {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
```

И также добавить

```
app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");
```

Надеюсь, кому то это поможет сэкономить время.